# Mask generation for segmentation

Tags: python-3.x, mask, image-segmentation

I have this kind of images (255 exactly):
[Example of delineation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNfIw.jpg)

I have to generate a mask for each of them automatically. For example, set all pixels in the bleu outline to zeros and set the others to one.
Does someone know a useful python's tool to achieve this task? Knowing that I know the exact position of the blue outline of the image above.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Do you have co-ordinates of blue pixels or is that image all you have?

Comment: Hi,
I have the coordinate of blue pixels.